# Checking whether NavigationStack contains View Controller error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to see if the View Controller is on Navigation stack and I'm lost in options of what to do. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
if ([((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).frontViewController.navigationController.viewControllers containsObject:SGAddNewServerViewController]) {
    <#statements#>
}
```

The problem is, how do I get the reference to `SGAddNewServerViewController` since I need to know its address with `objectAtIndex...` etc? XCode gives me an error of not knowing what it is and he's right.

Any ideas of how can I get a reference to it `without` knowing its exact address on the NavigationStack? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are trying to find the view controller based on its class. To do that, try this:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
UINavigationController *nav = delegate.frontViewController.navigationController;
for (UIViewController *controller in nav.viewControllers) {
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[SGAddNewServerViewController class]]) {
        SGAddNewServerViewController *sgController = (SGAddNewServerViewController *)controller;
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Please note that it is not a good idea to nest so many method/property calls into one line. It makes reading and debugging very difficult.

Comment: Agreed! It's a hell of a mess this method ;) Thanks for the help! It seems to be working!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over all controllers and check whether there is controller of type SGAddNewServerViewController

```
NSArray *viewControllers = ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).frontViewController.navigationController.viewControllers;
for (UIViewController *controller in viewControllers) {
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[SGAddNewServerViewController class]]) {
        //todo something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! A neat and sleek method you have here